# Prevent drag and drop navigation onto window scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chromium, electron

I have a problem whereby my html application 'navigated' to the content the user would drag and drop onto it. For example, dropping a text file on the application would cause the page to navigate to it.

I have solved this by registering an event handler on the document and attaching to dragenter, dragover, dragleave, and drop events. In the handler, I call preventDefault and stopPropagation, which works well when anything is dropped that doesn't match an expected (and handled) file type.

The problem is the user can drop onto a vertical scrollbar (by accident or otherwise) and the handler is not hit. I assume this is because the scrollbar isn't related to the document object in the same way a different child is.

How can I prevents a file drop on a vertical scroll bar from navigating???

```
var globalDnd = function (event) {
  // Prevent drag and drop navigation
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  // Other processing to handle certain file types

  return false;
};

$(document).on('dragenter dragover dragleave drop', globalDnd);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcoe6e9d/

Created a fiddle to show the problem. Resize the preview pane until a scrollbar appears then drag and drop and file on the bar. The page will navigate. If you drop it anywhere else on the preview pane, it won't.

Comment: And your example code is where?

Comment: You might have just stumbled upon an undiscovered bug!

Comment: Damn. Any pointers on where to file that for chromium?

Comment: This problem applies to both Atom Electron and Chromium browsers.
As a work around I am currently using the chromium flag 'enable-overlay-scrollbar'